# magento existing method rewrite with module

Tags: magento-1.9, module

I have few core files modifications in my app/code/local/Mage folder, but I wan't to make them work as magento module.

My example: I did few small modifications in method getValueHtml in file Mage/Bundle/Block/Sales/Order/Items/Renderer.php and now I wan't this rewritten method to be used.

I have followed online tutorials for blocks rewrite but it is not working for me. I'm missing something, but I can't figure it out. These are my module files:

app/code/local/MyCompany/Bundleproducts/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <MyCompany_Bundleproducts>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyCompany_Bundleproducts>
 </modules>
 <global>
  <blocks>
      <bundle>
         <rewrite>
              <sales_order>MyCompany_Bundleproducts_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer</sales_order>
          </rewrite>
      </bundle>
  </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/MyCompany/Bundleproducts/Block/Sales/Order/Items/Renderer.php:

```
<?php
class MyCompany_Bundleproducts_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer extends Mage_Bundle_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer
{
    public function getValueHtml($item)
    {
        if ($attributes = $this->getSelectionAttributes($item)) {
            return sprintf('%d', $attributes['qty']) . ' TEST ' .
                $this->escapeHtml($item->getName());
        } else {
            return $this->escapeHtml($item->getName());
        }
    }
}
```

and app/etc/modules/MyCompany_Bundleproducts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyCompany_Bundleproducts>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </MyCompany_Bundleproducts>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your block rewrite should be like this

```
<blocks>
      <bundle>
         <rewrite>
              <sales_order_items_renderer>MyCompany_Bundleproducts_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer</sales_order_items_renderer>
          </rewrite>
      </bundle>
  </blocks>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the complete path to the core block while overriding. This is the `config.xml`  code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
    <MyCompany_Bundleproducts>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </MyCompany_Bundleproducts>
 </modules>
 <global>
  <blocks>
      <bundle>
         <rewrite>
              <sales_order_items_renderer>MyCompany_Bundleproducts_Block_Sales_Order_Items_Renderer</sales_order_items_renderer>
          </rewrite>
      </bundle>
  </blocks>
 </global>
</config>
```